# How to see serde's generated implementation of Deserialize?

Tags: rust, serde

I use:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord)]
pub struct Foo {
    ...
}
```

I want to write a custom `Deserialize` for `Foo`.

How can I see the derived `Deserialize` code which `serde` generates?  I'd like to use that as a starting point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I see the derived Deserialize code which serde generates? I'd like to use that as a starting point.

You can ask rustc to dump the macro-expanded code (it's under "tools" in the rust playground). Since the rustc invocation is a bit complicated especially for a full-blown cargo-based project, rustacean extraordinaire David Tolnay has published a [`cargo expand`](https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand) command which you can `cargo install`, which basically does the annoying work for you.

I would not recommend it as a *starting point* when it comes to serde tho, the generated ser/de code is somewhat gnarly / hard to read. I would suggest going through [the serde documentation](https://serde.rs/) instead, especially [serde datamodel](https://serde.rs/data-model.html) and [custom serialization](https://serde.rs/custom-serialization.html).